# Ubuntu 13.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, ide

Do I retain all the software installed in Ubuntu12.10 after upgrading to 12.04
specially **eclipse**

Comment: You mean, after upgrading to _13_.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose dist-upgrade inside Ubuntu, all your packages will retain, except for those affected with upgrade. Upgrade tool also disables custom deb sources and PPA, so you will not receive updates until re-enable them manually or using tools like Y PPA Manager.

But if you decide to upgrade from CD or USB stick, it will eliminate all your custom packages, even if you choose update, not fresh install. If you doubt what to do, run dist-upgrade and look at packages list which it always shows before making changes.